# Non-administrator users denied access to Server 2008 R2 Remote Desktop Services

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, rds

I have a Remote Desktop server running Windows Server 2008 R2. Administrators can log into this server, but users who are not administrators receive an error message:

```
 To log on to this remote computer, you must have permission to log on through
 Terminal Services.
```

How do I give a user permission to log in via Remote Desktop if the user is not an administrator?

Comment: Part of me is wondering if you're some sort of automated spam bot... But honestly, I cannot understand you. At all. I understand English may not be your first language, but perhaps you could get someone to help you formulate this question better. I think you'd have a much better chance of someone being able to answer your question. Also try adding the user account you're trying to log in with to the Remote Desktop Users group on that computer.

Comment: thank you for your answer Ryan Ries, I translate with google I speak French, I'm sorry for the time you have taken to understand my question.
all my users a member of Remote Desktop. there is the administrator accounts that can connect to the remote desktop
thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand you correctly...

Try removing the user from the group that should grant remote access permissions and then adding them back in. Inherited group memberships can get confused by Windows from time to time.

If that doesn't work, try explicitly adding that user to the Remote Desktop Users group.

I think trying to go through the logs to determine the cause might be an exercise in futility for both parties, so those are the "quick fixes" to resolve this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to one of my clients on a Server 2012 R2 box. In the server manager I could see the disconnected sessions and I was unable to log them out. Ended up having to restart the server since no amount of group changing and permission giving would fix the issue. I did notice that one of their vendors was the last to login before it locked up. After the reboot I was able to login with out issue. The strange part was that any administrator level user could login and out with out any issue.